# DataTable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cell' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dataTable with local data consisting of 8 headers/rows. However I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cell' of undefined. I did some investigation and if I comment out only one of the columns then I am not getting error anymore. Seems my table can only show 7 rows. Do you know how to fix this?

```
           <tr>
            <th class="surname">SURNAME</th>
            <th class="firstName">FIRST NAME</th>
            <th class="loginEmail">LOGIN EMAIL</th>
            <th class="customer">CUSTOMER</th>
            <th class="capabilities">CAPABILITIES</th>
            <th class="currentStatus">STATUS</th>
            <th class="lastInviteSent">LAST EMAIL SENT</th>
            <th class="removeReq"></th>
        </tr>
```

data

```
                data.loginEmail = img.attr('data-email');
                data.firstName = img.attr('data-firstname');
                data.surname = img.attr('data-surname');
                data.customer = img.attr('data-customer');
                data.roles = img.attr('data-roles');
                data.currentStatus = img.attr('data-status');
                data.lastInviteSent = img.attr('data-lastemailsent');
                data.removeReq= img.attr('data-removeReq');
```

Code

```
    $('table.data-edit-invitations').dataTable({
            "sDom": '<"top">rtipl',
            "bPaginate": false,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sScrollY": "345px",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "bSortCellsTop": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'surname', "mData": "surname"},
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'firstName', "mData": "firstName"},
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'loginEmail', "mData": "loginEmail"},
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'customer', "mData": "customer"},
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'capabilities', "mData": "roles" },
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'currentStatus', "mData": "currentStatus" },
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'lastInviteSent', "mData": "lastInviteSent" },
                { "sType": 'string-case', "sClass": 'removeReq', "mData": "removeReq" }
            ],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable": '<span>No data available</span>',
                "sProcessing": "<span>Processing</span>"
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                   //some code here
            });
```

PS: When I comment out the removeReq in header and aoColumn. it works. also when I comment out the lastInviteSent and uncomment the removeReq it works. Just not working when both exist!

Comment: Post some code to describe your problem please!!

Comment: The particular column might have the inconsistent data. Show us some sample piece of code.

Comment: Hi, I added my code, data and HTML head section of table

Comment: If you put text in the last <th>, does this resolve your issue? Is the empty <th> rendered at all. Many of my issues with Datatables come from mismatch between header cells and columns in "aoColumns". As you can get either to work alone, you may need just be sure that last column renders. Try putting some test text in there and see.